# Why the expdp can't see this table? It's there?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-dump

- Does anyone know why this is happening?  I can select the table but
  can't export it.

  ```
  C:\>sqlplus myschema/myschema

  SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Aug 1 14:43:45 2016

  Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

  Last Successful login time: Mon Aug 01 2016 14:42:51 -04:00

  Connected to:
  Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
  With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics, and Real Application Testing opt
  ions

  SQL> select * from product;

          ID NAME
  ---------- --------------------
           1 sample_product_name

  SQL> exit
  Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64
  bit Production
  With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics, and Real Application Testing opt
  ions

  C:\>expdp myschema/myschema@oradev tables=product directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfi
  le=expdp_myschema.dmp logfile=expdp_myschema.log

  Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Mon Aug 1 14:44:16 2016

  Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

  Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit
  Production
  With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics, and Real Application Testing opt
  ions

  WARNING: Oracle Data Pump operations are not typically needed when connected to
  the root or seed of a container database.

  Starting "MYSCHEMA"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  myschema/********@oradev tables=prod
  uct directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=expdp_myschema.dmp logfile=expdp_myschema.l
  og
  Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
  Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 0 KB
  Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/MARKER
  **ORA-39166: Object MYSCHEMA.PRODUCT was not found** or could not be exported or imp
  orted.
  ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job
  Job "MYSCHEMA"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" completed with 2 error(s) at Mon Aug 1 14:4
  4:18 2016 elapsed 0 00:00:01
  ```

Comment: Your `sqlplus` command does not have a TNS alias.  Your `expdp` command does.  I would guess that you aren't connecting to the same database in both cases.

Comment: Are you sure it's a table and not some other objects like a view?

Comment: C:\>sqlplus myschema/myschema@oradev   
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Aug 2 08:42:27 2016
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.           
Last Successful login time: Tue Aug 02 2016 08:39:17 -04:00

SQL> select object_name, object_type from user_objects;
OBJECT_NAME  OBJECT_TYPE
-------------------------
PRODUCT    TABLE


I added the TNS and the table it's there.  I only have one Oracle instance running on my machine.  Sorry I don't know how to format my reply to make it clear and organized.

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter CONTENT=ALL at the end of your expdp command line,like this:

expdp myschema/myschema@oradev tables=product directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfi le=expdp_myschema.dmp logfile=expdp_myschema.log CONTENT=ALL

and execute it.